# How to convert svg to vector asset for android

Tags: android, svg, vector, assets

Is there a way to convert svg to vector asset supported by Android? I need this because I have several svg images and I want to use them in my android application development. However, currently i am unable to use them as they are not supported in android.

Comment: Google search turned up the following: https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/27/vector-graphics-in-android-part-1-svg/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can simply right click your `drawable` folder, select **new->Vector asset** and point it to your local SVG file.
This [Image](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/hRvujGpQMbQenJoCr_rAZ797YNmr7UI3ymN9UtCxX-iFFYD7I237LgQOVEOfpLlJXoJ4Jm5IxOLzAJWmNtElUX0umziYtlIvlW2L8IBjIx8gKzzPIWgzXsPua2MLPTpj9ESQ0yw) will help you.